# sql to extract list of values given a xmlstring (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

If i have an xml string like this

```
<xml>
    <myid>1</myid>
    <myid>2</myid>
    <myid>3</myid>
</xml>
```

how would i use sql to get just the list of myid's?

I was thinking i could try like this . The inner select returns the xml, but how do i get just the values?

```
   select ....   from (select xmltype('<xml><myid>1</myid><myid>2</myid><myid>3</myid></xml>') as xmlidlist from dual)
```

Comment: What intermediary are you using, SQL doesn't work on XML.  And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this to extract the values from a string, but it seems a bit like overkill.

```
select x.myid
from xmltable('/xml/*'
  passing xmltype('
<xml>
    <myid>1</myid>
    <myid>2</myid>
    <myid>3</myid>
</xml>')
  columns myid path '/myid') x;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/24152).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have that XML code in an XML type collumn in your SQL database. Maybe something like this?

```
select collumnName.query('/myid') from tableName
```